# Limit on Storing Objects/reference on CORBA Naming Service

Tags: java, object, naming, corba

I wanted to store the objects dynamically on Server developed using CORBA

I will be dynamically adding the objects reference to One particular context in Naming service .

Is there any limit on Naming Service of the CORBA to store max no. of the Objects references on tree structure ?

Answer (score 1):

I think that most implementations have a maximum of CORBA::ULong object references at one level, that is the maximum size of a CORBA sequence. Maybe some implementations have a smaller max, you have to check your naming service implementation.

Comment: **CORBA::ULong object references** what is it ? can you explain?

Comment: CORBA::ULong is a type, in Java it's mapped to int, which maximum is 2^31 -1